# When I press tab in the python terminal, an annoying "bck:?" prompt comes up to search command history

Tags: python, macos, terminal, tabs, zsh

When I type in the python terminal, say, exactly these commands and `<KEYSTROKES>`:

```py
for i in range(5): !<ENTER>
!<TAB>
```

the instant I press tab, I am prompted by an annoying box beneath the terminal (and an alarm ping) that parses my command history and fills in a command. If I press ESC, it goes away. How can I stop this behaviour?

```
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 26 2022, 01:05:56) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> for i in range(5):
... ...
bck:?
```

As I said, when I press `esc`, this option disappears. It occurs for python 3.11, 3.10, and 3.7. I haven't tried other versions. Does anyone recognize this?

Comment: As an update, I've found that it is only the MacPorts installation of python giving this issue. If I install it via the dmg files on the python website, no such problem occurs.

Comment: You should make an answer with that and mark it as resolved, I'm sure other people would benefit from finding the solution.